# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-2.0

I've cloned [this](https://github.com/brechtb86/dotnet/tree/master/brechtbaekelandt.ldap) code from github. The code enables to authenticate
users against Active Directory. More [here](https://www.brechtbaekelandt.net/blog/post/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-aspnet-core-2-and-managing-users)

When I run it, it throws the error in the title. How would you modify the program
to have some test DB and be able to trace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a value in your config for `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection`. It would seem that the confusion is that the GitHub project in question has no `appsettings.json`, and actually defines this config key in `appsettings.github.json`, which is not a config file that will be loaded in by default. If you rename that file to `appsettings.json`, that may be enough to fix the issue.